# Android resize bitmap keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I have a custom view (1066 x 738), and I am passing a bitmap image (720x343). I want to scale the bitmap to fit in the custom view without exceeding the bound of the parent.

[image]

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

How should I calculate the bitmap size?

How I calculate the new width/height:

```
    public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap b, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        int bWidth = b.getWidth();
        int bHeight = b.getHeight();

        int nWidth = reqWidth;
        int nHeight = reqHeight;

        float parentRatio = (float) reqHeight / reqWidth;

        nHeight = bHeight;
        nWidth = (int) (reqWidth * parentRatio);

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, nWidth, nHeight, true);
    }
```

But all I am achieving is this:

[image]

Comment: You could add a `scaleType` flag to your custom view's XML.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: It is not an imageView !

Comment: Ah, I (wrongly) assumed your custom view extended ImageView... my fault

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You should try using a transformation matrix built for `ScaleToFit.CENTER`. For example:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, reqWidth, reqHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
```

Comment: not working for me. I tried reducing the image size, in resolutions, using this, but didn't work.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra you can then call `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(out, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);` ,this will reduce image size.

Comment: @matiash , Please give a look on this issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927337/scaling-bitmaps-of-huge-images-from-url-into-image-view-according-to-device-reso

Comment: working for me..