# Android Scaled Bitmap gets Cropped

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to create a scaled bitmap which fits in the Custom View but whenever I perform the operation the width gets cropped while the height of the bitmap fits into the custom view.

```
bitmapq = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(custHeight*bitmap.getWidth())/bitmap.getHeight(),custHeight, true);
```

Custom View height - 1089.
Custom View width- 1180.
Width of bitmap - 2368.
Height of bitmap - 4208

Comment: what is the width of custom view

Comment: Width of custom view is 1180

Comment: see the answer that is right by Hi Iamforgatto

Comment: you dont need a scaled `Bitmap` at all: if it is your custom view then draw your original `Bitmap` on a scaled `Canvas`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the scaled bitmap to be of the exact size of your custom view regardless of its aspect ratio, you can use this:

```
bitmapq = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, cusWidth, custHeight, true);
```

In this way, the scaled bitmap exacly fits your custom view's boundaries.

Comment: The image gets stretched with this code.I want to maintain the aspect ratio even if it leaves some space on  sides of the bitmap.

Comment: @zek54 Which class does your custom view extend? If it extends `ImageView` so you won't need to scale/crop the bitmap manually, it takes care of this work by itself.

Comment: @zek54 Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961797/android-resize-bitmap-keeping-aspect-ratio). It may be helpful.