# scaled bitmap according to device resolution

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-glide

I am getting strange issue of White blank screen when i try to set image inside my image view after scaling it from bitmap.

I am getting random size images from server , I just need to show them in my image view without loose in quality of image. i have taken one layout and add image view dynamically through code.

Here is what i am doing in code :-

Getting Url form server and scaling it accordingly :-

```
url="http://www.petstory.co/attached_king_photos/hotel/7/attached_d67e2689e0d3370f7e76b5bba9f8e875e42a2e39.jpg"

     AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
                    return bitmap;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if (result.getHeight() > 7000){
                        getResizedBitmap(result, 4000, 4000, image);
                    }else{
                        getResizedBitmap(result, 800, 800, image);
                    }

                }
            }.execute(imageUrl);


public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
     



     public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight, final ImageView image) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        final int wantedgeightis = newHeight;

        float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity;
        float scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity;
//        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
//        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // create a matrix for the manipulation


        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
       matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        final Bitmap resizedBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);

//        final Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//
                if (wantedgeightis == 4000) {
                    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                } else {
                    int bitmapWidth = resizedBitmap.getWidth();
                    int bitmapHeight = resizedBitmap.getHeight();
                    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, bitmapHeight);
                    image.setLayoutParams(params);
                    image.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                }


            }
        });
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

The Url of image which i am setting in above methods is :-

http://www.petstory.co/attached_king_photos/hotel/7/attached_d67e2689e0d3370f7e76b5bba9f8e875e42a2e39.jpg

i am testing on nexus , rest images are aprearing as expected but only this image displays me white blank screen

I even make use of Glide and pisacco getting same issue for this image or sometimes highly distorted image get appear on screen.

**Here is the code of Glide which i used** :-

```
Glide.with(this) //passing context
                        .load(imageUrl) //passing your url to load image.
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.petzview_logo) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                        .error(R.drawable.petz_test)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                       .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                        .dontAnimate()
                       .override(700, 4000)
                        .into(image);
```

**I Even tried with bellow code too** :-

```
Glide.with(this)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.petzview_logo)
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(new ViewTarget<ImageView, GlideDrawable>(image) {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation anim) {
                                Toast.makeText(HowAboutHere.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                image.setImageDrawable(resource.getCurrent());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                Toast.makeText(HowAboutHere.this, "Glide image load failed for %s -> %s" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
```

**By using .override(700, 4000) , the image is getting displayed but streched and if i change value to  .override(700, 4100) , then blank white screen start getting displayed** due to very large image size

Or Should i First Save image from URL to any file and then retrieve the image from file and apply inSample size bitmap algo on it this will be time taking and with utilize more memory and make application slow.As mentioned in below two links :-

[Best method to download image from url in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

However here i am also posting the image look like when i use Bitmap code form displaying huge image from URL

[image]

**As you can see the image is still getting stretched**.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks!!!